# React Reach Router - Reload the entire tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, reach-router

I have the following main class

```
const MainApp = ({ children }) => {
  
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <div className="h-screen pb-14">
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};
```

and then my router  like this

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <MainApp path="/">
        <MainPage path="/" />
        <SubtitlesPage path="subtitles" />
        <MobileAppPage path="mobileApp" />
        <SubtitlesBrowsePage path="subtitles/browse" />
        <ShopPage path="shop" />
      </MainApp>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

When I navigate from "/" to "/mobileApp" for example, he's reloading the whole tree (Header and footer).

When I navigate from "/subtitles" to "/subtitles/Browse" he does not.

My goal is to not reload the header/footer part when he switches from "/" to any other page(but obv he needs to load the whole tree if we go directly to "/mobileApp".

What am I missing?

**EDIT** Ok ... the issue was coming from my navigation! I was using simple  tag instead of   provided by React Router... Good to know ;)